# Tableview Cell size not changing? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I dragged an dropped a table view Controller from the object library and changed the cell's row height to 300.However , when I run it in the simulator , the cell remains the same standard size.Why is this?

**Images** : 
[image]
[image]

**Constraints** :
[image]

**Output** : 
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Storyboard, if you know the cell height, set the Table View's Row Height property on the Size Inspector tab, not the cell's:

[image: UITableView's Size Inspector page]

Answer (score 3):

You can set custom row height example add ;

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 100.0;//Your custom row height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have given all the constraints in the cell . They have to be connected from top to bottom.
2. Make sure that the class of content view inside the custom cell is UIView .(I have done the same mistake )

   press content view -> see identity inspector on right -> class should be UI view .
   [image: custom cell elements]

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate of the tableview and set the heightforrowatindexpath method.